# Change colour of part of an image Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, image, colors

[image]

I have an internal website that has a floor plan, I have smart lights in my house, If the light is on this image is shown in the floor plan. One of the bulbs is multi-coloured. I can get the RGB value from the bulb, what is the easiest way to change the yellow part of this picture to the 
RGB value I get back from the bulb using javascript/html? (Bearing in mind the bulbs are polled every 10 secs)

Comment: What is the image format? In SVG it's possible, so try to convert it to SVG first.

Comment: Please add some code instead of an image of a bulb ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this with the following :)

```
// Set colour of light bulb
        function set_bulb_colour(img_id, rgb_colour)
        {
            var img = new Image();

            img.onload = function()
            {
                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

                canvas.width = img.width;
                canvas.height = img.height;

                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

                var image_data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                var data = image_data.data;

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4)
                {
                    if (data[i + 3] == 0)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    // If the pixel is yellow set it to the new colour
                    if (data[i] > 200 && data[i + 2] < 100)
                    {
                        data[i] = rgb_colour[0];
                        data[i + 1] = rgb_colour[1];
                        data[i + 2] = rgb_colour[2];
                    }
                }

                ctx.putImageData(image_data, 0, 0);

                $('img#living_room_light_emoji').attr('src', canvas.toDataURL());
            }

            img.src = 'images/light_bulb.png';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to switch to svg icon. You can take ready icons from [fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery) for example. then the switching of color is very easy.